# Spark unable to filter by string containing folder path

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a strange behavior of the spark sql query API, example:

I have the following dataset:

```
+---+-------------------------------+--------+
|key|value                          |someData|
+---+-------------------------------+--------+
|1  |AAA                            |5       |
|1  |VVV                            |6       |
|1  |DDDD                           |8       |
|3  |rrerw                          |9       |
|4  |RRRRR                          |13      |
|6  |AAAAABB                        |15      |
|6  |C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe|20      |
+---+-------------------------------+--------+
```

Where value is of type String,

When I write the following command, the last row in filtered out:

```
data.filter(col("value").notEqual("C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe")).show();
```

Applying the following command fail to filter the last row out:

```
data.createTempView("temp");
spark.sql("select * from temp where value != 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe'").show();
```

Filtering by any other value e.g. "AAA" works. Any suggestions?

EDIT: entire code:

```
public class main {
    private static StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
            DataTypes.createStructField("key", DataTypes.IntegerType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("someData", DataTypes.IntegerType, true)
    });

    public static class Dummy implements Serializable {
        int key;
        String value;
        int someData;

        public Dummy() {
            this.key = 1;
            this.value = "";
            this.someData = 0;
        }

        public Dummy(int key, String value, int someData) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.someData = someData;
        }

        public int getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(int key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getSomeData() {
            return someData;
        }

        public void setSomeData(int someData) {
            this.someData = someData;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AnalysisException {
        String master = "local[*]";
        SparkConf sparkConfiguration = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test!").setMaster(master);
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConfiguration).getOrCreate();
        spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");

        List<Dummy> intArray = Arrays.asList(new Dummy(1, "AAA", 5), new Dummy(1, "VVV", 6), new Dummy(1, "DDDD", 8), new Dummy(3, "rrerw", 9), new Dummy(4, "RRRRR", 13), new Dummy(6, "AAAAABB", 15), new Dummy(6, "C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe", 20));
        Dataset<Dummy> data = spark.createDataset(intArray, Encoders.bean(Dummy.class));

        Dataset<Row> rawMapping = data.map((MapFunction<Dummy, Row>) row -> RowFactory.create(
                row.getKey(),
                row.getValue() == "" ? null : row.getValue(),
                row.getSomeData()
        ), RowEncoder.apply(schema));

        System.out.println("rawMapping");
        rawMapping.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id()).show(false);

        rawMapping.filter(col("value").notEqual("C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe")).show();


        rawMapping.createTempView("temp");

        spark.sql("select * from temp where value != 'VVV'").show();
        spark.sql("select * from temp where value != 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe'").show();

    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It works fine for me.

Comment: @OmG what version of Spark do you use?

Comment: The Spark version is `2.2.1`.

Comment: @OmG I have validated it doesn't work on 2.2.1, I added the entire code, could you try it out?

Comment: Sorry. I've run the exact code in pyspark not in java.

Comment: @OmG oh, must be a Java thing so... if it was you who flagged the question to be closed could you remove it as it really doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try `"""`

```
spark.sql("""select * from temp where value != 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe'""")
     .show(false)
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, I am using Java (forgot to mention, added to question), where triple `"""` is not supported. Do you know what is the Java equivalent of it?

Comment: Not sure about Java's string interpolation. But here is a work around you can try. `        String path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe".replace("\\","\\\\");
        String qry = "select * from temp where value != " + path;
`

Comment: This actually works! can you explain what is actually going on here?

Comment: Not a java guy actually but when you search for the path the double `backslashes` were converted to `single backslashes` that's why it didn't return the correct result. This is just a workaround. Not sure if there are any alternatives for `string interpolation `or `raw` string literals in java.